# (ArgumentError) Ruby : wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, arguments

```
def visualization (name, age, looks)
  age.to_s
  puts name + ' is ' + age + ' years old and looks ' + looks
end

visualization (name = 'Mary', age = 5, looks = 'bad')

#=> `visualization': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: (1) Remove the space between `visualization` and it's arguments. (2) `age.to_s` doesn't mutate `age`. Just use `age.to_s` instead of `age` during concatenation.

Comment: Also are you really writing a program to rate toddler's looks? xd

Comment: Could you please add some information to the question? Like, what research have you done to fix the problem, what documentation have you read, which parts of the documentation did you understand, and which not, why was that research and documentation not helpful, what steps did you do to debug the problem, etc.? That way, you avoid answerer wasting both their and your time explaining things you already know, and/or things you already researched and didn't help you. At the moment, it looks like you just dumped an error message into the textbox and expect somebody else to do your job for you.

Comment: my name argument become array then i send the arguments visualization (name = 'Ann', age = 2). p name.instance_of? String #=> False    p name #=> ["Ann", 2]      Someone have to rate toddlers :-D

Answer (score 3):

So the **main** problem here is the space between `visualization` and its arguments. When ruby sees `visualization (name = 'Mary', age = 5, looks = 'bad')` it recognizes `visualization as a method (because it has argument), but it first tries to calculate the expression in the brackets:

```
(name = 'Mary', age = 5, looks = 'bad')
```

This on its own is a valid ruby expression, but it might be quite a surprise to see how ruby interpretes it:

```
name = ('Mary', (age = 5), (looks = 'bad'))
```

Resulting in `name` being `['Mary', 5, 'bad']`, `age` being `5` and `looks` being 'bad'.

As the expression is just an assignment, it returns the assigned value (array `['Mary', 5, 'bad']`) which is then passed to your `visualisation` method. Since you are passing a single array and your method expects three arguments, you're getting the error.

AS per solution, just drop the space between method call and its arguments. You also don't need to name the arguments - this is not Python - here keywords are defined explicitly and you actually creating local variables by doing so.

There are some other issues there as well, but @Stefan has covered that already.

Answer (score 0):

`age.to_s` doesn't alter the `age` object (you can't change the class of an object in Ruby), it merely *returns* a new string.
So you either have to re-assign age via `age = age.to_s` or move the `to_s` call to where it is needed:

```
def visualization(name, age, looks)
  puts name + ' is ' + age.to_s + ' years old and looks ' + looks
end
```

You can use string interpolation instead which is more idiomatic and makes `to_s` calls superfluous:

```
def visualization(name, age, looks)
  puts "#{name} is #{age} years old and looks #{looks}"
end
```

When calling this method, you pass the arguments via:

```
visualization('Mary', 5, 'cute')
#            ^ and no space here
```

The assignments in your code don't make much sense. You probably wanted to have [keyword arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments): (note the colons)

```
def visualization(name:, age:, looks:)
  puts "#{name} is #{age} years old and looks #{looks}"
end

visualization(name: 'Mary', age: 5, looks: 'cute')
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Ruby isn't whitespace sensitive in the same way as languages like Python, but there are places where whitespace is confusing to the parser. In addition, while some of your code works, it's not idiomatic (it reads like JavaScript) and is less performant. Finally, in-place operators are usually bang methods, so you need to distinguish between methods that change the receiver and ones that return a new result.

### Idiomatic Alternative

I changed some of your code for cultural reasons, but kept it close to your intent data-wise. The rest is intended to show how to do what you want more idiomatically.

Here's a more idiomatic and parser-friendly alternative that uses string interpolation:

```rb
def user_data(name, age, status)
  pp "name is #{name}; age is #{age}; status is #{status}"
end
```

String interpolation using the embedded expression operator `#{expr}` within double quotes is often more efficient, and implicitly converts values to strings if it supports a #to_s or #to_str method. The [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p) and [Kernel#pp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p) methods ensure that the method returns a value, as well as printing to *$stdout*.

Alternatively, you can also use other constructs like here-documents, [String#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), [String#format](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#method-i-format), and many others to construct printf-style interpolations, but the example above is easiest to read for most Rubyists, and should generally be your go-to if you follow most of the popular Ruby style guides, including [RuboCop's default style guide](https://rubystyle.guide/).

#### Note: Interpolation Works with Frozen String Literals

As a final note, this type of interpolation will also work even if you have the frozen-string literal "magic comment" enabled at the top of your file, e.g.:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

which is often considered a best practice by [RuboCop](https://rubocop.org/) and other similar tools.